# Calculate the footprint along the track between two distant squares

Tags: postgis, gdal, polygon-creation, path

I am trying to achieve this kind of operation programatically, using preferably **PostGIS** (or else **GDAL**)

[image]

Is there any well-known operation doing this?

My use case is the following:

- I have two squares representing the footprint of the pictures that a satellite shot at the start and the end of a semi-orbit.
- I would like to be able to reconstruct the polygon of the area that has been scanned along the path between these two snapshots.
- The width of the swath is of course constant.
- The start and end squares can not be aligned, and therefore the resulting polygon shall be calculated on the envelope (and not only a dilation of the path). In that sense the above picture doesnt represent exactly what I need (ie: the resultant shape shall be wider in its center, since resulting of the 'dragging' of the first shape to reach the second).

Comment: Is the desired end shape the convex hull of all the vertices in the two input shapes?

Comment: Possible solution depends on how accurate the result we want to achieve.(??) ST_ConvexHull is simplest way, but to do it right I think we have to count how this geometry will look like all the way from point A to B and join this geometries... or else differencies between this geometries are ariring from projection

Comment: Thank you for the anwers and the tips. I tried the convex hull, but the result isn't exactly what I was expecting. Indeed it's 'painting' the strip between my two shapes, but it is larger that the satellite swath would be in reality. I think the problem is that I create the convex hull on the wrong projection...